# One line linux sudo change password

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I need to change a password with one line which also includes sudo.

I know you can echo the sudo password like so:

`echo "password" | sudo -S {command}`

and I can change the password like so:

`echo "user:passwd" | sudo chpasswd`

I tried the following but it doesn't look like the echos are executed correctly:

`echo "root_password" | echo "user:passwd" | sudo -S chpasswd`

and this works but hangs on a prompt:

`echo "root_password\nuser:passwd" | sudo -S chpasswd`

What would be the correct combination to execute this command correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to use a nested shell, since you can't stack pipes like that:

```
echo "root_password" | sudo -S sh -c 'echo "user:passwd" | chpasswd'
```

The `echo "root_password" | sudo -S` stays the same, the only thing that is changed is that we create a new shell inside sudo (`sh`), which runs a string literal as a command (`-c 'echo "user:passwd" | chpasswd'`).

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, you saved me a lot of time and stress trying to figure this out.

Answer (score -1):

Simply use `echo password | sudo passwd --stdin username`.

Comment: This would still cause sudo to ask for a password, which is explicitly _not_ what OP wanted.

Comment: Have you tried it? On my machine the password is changed flawless, without any blocking prompt.

Comment: Got it now, it's the sudo password which is not required in my machine. Sorry, my fault. :-)